# How to pass any named an multiple argument to the shell script?

Tags: shell

How to pass any named an multiple argument to the shell script?

Ex:

```
shell.sh --arg1 value --arg2 value --arg3 value4 --arg4 value5 --arg5 vlue6
```

(or) it can be like.

```
shell.sh --arg2 value --arg5 value --arg6 value4 --arg7 value5 --arg8 vlue6 arg9 value
```

(or) it can be like

```
shell.sh --arg10 value --arg11 value
```

So argument name is not constant, i have tried to handle in getops, but i did not got correct result.

Help me to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use the `shift` [built in](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html)?

Comment: Why don't you show us what you tried? Right now it looks like you are requesting a free code writing service.

Comment: ` i have tried to handle in getops` - pls put the code here..